# OrderByDescending() without effect

Tags: c#

I have that class

```
public class jQGridModel
{
    public List<jQGridModelItem> Items { get; set; }

    public class jQGridModelItem
    {
        public DBUser UserItem { get; set; }
        public int ItemsSold { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the `DBUser` class (generated by Entity Framework)

```
public class DBUser 
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string PromoCode { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I have `jQGridModel` object with some `Items`. And here's the 'simple' problem - I want to sort the `Items` list asc/desc basing on the `UserName`

I've tried

```
jQGridModel result = new jQGridModel();
result.Items = GetItems();

result.Items = result.Items.OrderByDescending(x => x.UserItem.UserName).ToList();
```

but I see that the collenction order does't change. What am I doing wrong ?

The complete code:

```
        var query = (from x in db.User
                     where (...)
                     select x);

        var totalRecords = query.Count();

        jQGridModel result = new jQGridModel();

        result.Items = query.OrderBy(x => x.UserID).Skip(page * pageSize)
                            .Take(pageSize)
                            .Select(x => new jQGridModel.jQGridModelItem
                            {
                                UserItem = x,
                                ItemsSold = (from o in db.Order
                                             where
                                                 o.PromoCode.Equals(x.PromoCode)
                                             select o).Count()
                            })
                            .ToList();


  result.Items = result.Items.OrderByDescending(x => x.UserItem.UserName).ToList();
```

Comment: Instead of assigning `result.Items` twice, what happens if you do `var items = result.Items.OrderByDescending(x => x.UserItem.UserName).ToList();`? Does the collection re-order?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong from these snippets. Please post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @mattytommo that wont fix the problem if there is one

Comment: After looking at your linq query, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it.

Comment: Like @Jon Skeet said, a complete snippet is needed - we don't know what GetItems() is. My _guess_ is it returns an IQueryable, and that the UserItem property is lazy loaded, so the result is first returned, which is why the order doesn't appear to change, and _then_ the UserName is grabbed (via lazy load), so you aren't actually getting the result you want to filter on until after the original list is returned. I reserve the right to be completely wrong, of course. :)

Comment: @jesus.tesh Good thinking. Perhaps your right to be completely wrong will pan out when we find out that all the `UserName` values are identical. >.>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have said it "doesn't return an IQueryable", which it doesn't. So, you get your list in the order you get it, *then* you are trying to order by a (most likely) lazy loaded property. So you aren't really doing what you think you are doing. :)

<del>Either place the UserName as a property of the jQGridModelItem, or if you really need the full DBUser entity, you can load it up first, then sort.</del>

**EDIT**

Actually, just specify the proper ordering in the initial orderby:

```
result.Items = query.OrderBy(x => x.UserName).Skip(page * pageSize)
                            .Take(pageSize)
                            .Select(x => new jQGridModel.jQGridModelItem
                            {
                                UserItem = x,
                                ItemsSold = (from o in db.Order
                                             where
                                                 o.PromoCode.Equals(x.PromoCode)
                                             select o).Count()
                            })
                            .ToList();
```